# How can I use OpenType Font in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, fonts

Is there a way I can use an OTF file with libGDX.

The following throws an exception:

```
gameFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/font.otf"));
```

Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Invalid padding.

This is the same error thrown if I were to try to use a non font file type as well. (i.e. .png .mp3 etc). I have been able to use .fnt files in the past. Is there anyway around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but you could create a font for libgdx from a `.otf` using the Hiero tool to convert your font, or create one at runtime but (like the author of [this site](http://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/introduction-to-the-libgdx-library.32592/) says), it's something that you should try to avoid.

An example of how to load an `.otf` font can be found [here](http://ilearnsomethings.blogspot.mx/2014/02/libgdx-generate-bitmap-fonts-for-any.html)

Comment: Thank you. I managed to use the Hiero Tool and it worked fine. I appreciate the help.